# Video content in left div not properly functioning inChrome

Tags: html, css

I created the website at [www.parkslopecc.com](http://www.parkslopecc.com). I recently noticed that the video on the top left of the home page does not play in Chrome, but it does in IE.

If I remove the `float: left` from the containing div, the video does play, but the the columns get messed up. After looking around, I tried using `display: inline-block`. While it does produce 2 columns, it doesn't display properly with the current content and everything else as it.

Rather than starting all over again, I'm hoping someone here can help. get the page to display as it now does but with the video able to play! (Also, in Chrome, all the videos appear dark until played.) Thanks! Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to the video's parent (div) - (A.K.A video-wrapper) `z-index: 1;`

The problem is that the div after the video-wrapper (`.bodytext`) has `position:relative` so it cover the video-wrapper and not let the user to click on it.

When you set `z-index:1` to the video-wrapper, it will above the text.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Sure glad I didn't tear the whole thing up and start over!